# Applying multiple formulae to selected columns of dataframe in R

Tags: r, function

With my dataset "chile2", I am doing following calculations:

```
Tab<-with(chile2,table(Q27,Q12_1_TEXT))
Tab<-as.data.frame.matrix(Tab)
```

I want the output like below (only 4 columns are shown):
   [image]

I am trying below code to do manipulations to the columns, which is strangely calculating few columns but not all:

```
 for(col in names(T1)){
    T1[col]=(T1[col]*100)/colSums(T1)
 }

  for(t in names(T1)){
    T1[t]=paste(round(T1[t],0),"%")
  }
```

The "All" row can be added after this.

Any other better way to do this?

```
dput(chile2)

structure(list(Q27 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Si", 
"No"), class = "factor"), Q12_1_TEXT = c("Abertis Autopistas S.a.", 
"Accenture", "Adessa Falabella", "Administradora de Fondos de Cesantía", 
"AES GENER S.A.", "AFP HABITAT S.A.", "Agrícola Ariztía", "Agrosuper S.A.", 
"Aguas de Antofagasta S.A.", "AIG Chile Compañía de Seguros Generales S.A.", 
"Arcos Dorados Restaurantes de Chile Ltda", "Artel", "Arval - Relsa", 
"Banchile Inversiones", "BANCO INTERNACIONAL", "BASF CHILE SA", 
"BBVA Chile", "BOEHRINGER INGELHEIM LTDA", "Bredenmaster S.A.", 
"Caja de Compensación 18 de Septiembre")), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000100788>, .Names = c("Q27", 
"Q12_1_TEXT"))
```

Comment: You may need `addmargins(100*prop.table(Tab, 2), 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dcast the `chile2` data to get the length by Q27 variable. Then find the proportions using `prop.table` and append it with '%' character using `paste0()`

```
library('data.table')
Tab <- dcast(chile2, Q27 ~ Q12_1_TEXT, fun.aggregate = length, value.var = 'Q12_1_TEXT')
Tab[, 2:ncol(Tab) := lapply(.SD, function(x) paste0( prop.table(x)*100, "%")), .SDcols = -1 ]
Tab
#    Q27 AES GENER S.A. AFP HABITAT S.A. AIG Chile Compañía de Seguros Generales S.A. Abertis Autopistas S.a.
# 1:  Si           100%               0%                                         100%                      0%
# 2:  No             0%             100%                                           0%                    100%
```

Now you can add `All` row.

---

**EDIT:**

I converted `Q27` column of `Tab` data table from factor  to character so it is consistent. Then, I added `Total` column which takes row sum from column 2 to last column. The `.SDcols = -1` includes all columns except the first column, because it is of character type. We want to work with numeric columns when making row sums. Then I created the `ALL` row, so that it can be `rbind` later. Then the proportions with in the data is computed and `%` character is added to it. Finally, the `Tab` and `ALL` data are combined together using `rbindlist`.

```
library('data.table')
Tab <- dcast(chile2, Q27 ~ Q12_1_TEXT, fun.aggregate = length, value.var = 'Q12_1_TEXT')
Tab[, Q27 := as.character(Q27)]  # convert column one from factor to character
Tab[, Total := rowSums(.SD), .SDcols = -1 ]  # add Total column
ALL <- as.list( c( Q27 = "ALL", colSums(Tab[, 2:ncol(Tab)]) ) )  # create ALL row
Tab[, 2:ncol(Tab) := lapply(.SD, function(x) paste0( prop.table(x)*100, "%")), .SDcols = -1 ]  # find proportions
Tab <- rbindlist(l = list(Tab, ALL)) # row bind Tab and ALL
```

**Output:**

```
str(Tab)
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    3 obs. of  22 variables:
# $ Q27                                         : chr  "Si" "No" "ALL"
# $ AES GENER S.A.                              : chr  "100%" "0%" "1"
# $ AFP HABITAT S.A.                            : chr  "0%" "100%" "1"
# $ AIG Chile Compañía de Seguros Generales S.A.: chr  "100%" "0%" "1"
# $ Abertis Autopistas S.a.                     : chr  "0%" "100%" "1"
# $ Accenture                                   : chr  "100%" "0%" "1"
# $ Adessa Falabella                            : chr  "0%" "100%" "1"
# $ Administradora de Fondos de Cesantía        : chr  "0%" "100%" "1"
# $ Agrosuper S.A.                              : chr  "0%" "100%" "1"
# $ Agrícola Ariztía                            : chr  "0%" "100%" "1"
# $ Aguas de Antofagasta S.A.                   : chr  "0%" "100%" "1"
# $ Arcos Dorados Restaurantes de Chile Ltda    : chr  "0%" "100%" "1"
# $ Artel                                       : chr  "100%" "0%" "1"
# $ Arval - Relsa                               : chr  "0%" "100%" "1"
# $ BANCO INTERNACIONAL                         : chr  "100%" "0%" "1"
# $ BASF CHILE SA                               : chr  "0%" "100%" "1"
# $ BBVA Chile                                  : chr  "100%" "0%" "1"
# $ BOEHRINGER INGELHEIM LTDA                   : chr  "100%" "0%" "1"
# $ Banchile Inversiones                        : chr  "0%" "100%" "1"
# $ Bredenmaster S.A.                           : chr  "0%" "100%" "1"
# $ Caja de Compensación 18 de Septiembre       : chr  "0%" "100%" "1"
# $ Total                                       : chr  "35%" "65%" "20"
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Comment: This one's working, I am trying now to understand how it works, thanks

Comment: If I add a total column to Tab with - Tab2<-Tab%>%mutate("Total"=rowSums(Tab[,2:ncol(Tab)])), then the code you suggested s giving error: Error in `[.data.frame`(Tab2, , `:=`(2:ncol(Tab2), lapply(.SD, function(x) paste0(prop.table(x) *  : 
  unused argument (.SDcols = -1)

Comment: I think its because Tab2 is not data table

Comment: The output I shown in the question is what I want. Your code works fine . data table issue resolved. But adding "All" row using rbind is not working after this.rbind(Tab2,c("All",colSums(Tab2[,2:ncol(Tab2)])))

Comment: Yes, I added code to convert Q27 to character then the old code also working. Is it because rbind works like this?

Comment: Thanks, this works fine now. However I realized I will do this for many variables , so why not create a function for this whole code. may be I will post a new question after some research, dcast is giving error in the function.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `base R` using `addmargins` and `prop.table`.  From the `table` output in the OP's post, apply `prop.table` with `margin` specified as 2 (for columnwise).  Create the `Sum` row with `addmargins`.  Then, we multiply the rows except the last one with 100 and `paste` the `%` to the values

```
res <- addmargins(prop.table(Tab, 2), 1)
res[-nrow(res),] <- paste0(res[-nrow(res), ] * 100, "%")
dimnames(res)[[1]][3] <- "All"
names(dimnames(res)) <- NULL
res[,1:3]
#   Abertis Autopistas S.a. Accenture Adessa Falabella
#Si  0%                      100%      0%              
#No  100%                    0%        100%            
#All 1                       1         1
```

Comment: This is giving error - Error in margin.table(x, margin) : 'x' is not an array

Comment: @SandhyaGhildiyal  I was using only your `Tab` output based on the 'chile' data you provided.  It is not giving me any problem